# Python. Searched for 2 days. Can't find answer. While loop for "response" for created game

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

Please help.  I am so sorry but I cannot find an answer to make the loop stop after three questions.  I've searched for two days.  I am brand new at this and trying to teach myself.

Everything runs property until I try to limit the questions to 3.

```
def get_answer(answer_number):
    if answer_number == 1:
        return "I don't like that question.  I'm not answering you."
    elif answer_number == 2:
        return "Really!?  I'm not answering that."
    elif answer_number == 3:
        return "Ummm, you already know the answer so why are you asking me?"
    elif answer_number == 4:
        return "Focus."
    elif answer_number == 5:
        return "Yawn."

r = random.randint(1, 5)
response = get_answer(r)(tries=3)

while True:
    print("What is your question?")
    question = input()
    if response < 4:
        print(response)
        print()
else:
    print("Would you like to continue with more questions?")
    reply = input().lower()
    if reply == "Y":
        print("Your card will be billed another 1₵.")
    if reply == "N":
        print("Okay.  Amscray!")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. We are not interested in your personal frustrations; we are interested only in your **question** - ideally, asked explicitly, starting with a question word like "why" or "how", and ending with a question mark (`?`). "Please help" [is not answerable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/), and "everything works fine until" does not describe a problem nor ask a question.

Comment: As for the code shown: think carefully about the indentation - specifically, how the `else` block should be indented.

Comment: Also: think carefully about what `reply = input().lower()` means. Could the resulting `reply` ever be equal to `"Y"`? How?

Answer (score 0):

Beacuse you are using `lower()` method in your `reply` input and checking for uppercase "Y" and "N"
simply replace the `lower()` method with the `upper()` method like this :-

```
reply = input().upper()
```